# How to show in jQuery the active div in <ul> after toggle?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a nested  menu with content divs that toggle onclick. By default, when a page loads, the menu shows with all Content divs hidden. I am trying to show when the page loads (without any clicks) the Content div that is active (class="active"). 
This is my HTML:

```
<ul> 
 <li><h3 class="toggle_action"> Mailing Lists</h3>  // toggle trigger
  <ul class="div_toggle">  // the content div
   <li><h3 class="toggle_action"><a href="/list" class="active">Overview</a></h3></li>
   <li>...another link...</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
(function ($) {
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".div_toggle").slideUp();
        $(".active").Show();
        $(".toggle_action").click(function(){
            $(this).next(".div_toggle").slideToggle("slow");
        });         
    });    
  })(jQuery);
```

I've searched for hours but can only find code that shows/hide onclick, and I must be missing something to do this on page load only. Please help point me in right direction!

Comment: And your error console shows what errors?

Comment: You're showing the element, but hiding the parent (`.div_toggle`). The element will not be visible if the container it is in is hidden.

Comment: valid markup needed for achieving the goals.

Comment: sorry guys I'm a newbie at this, so please bear with me. @Juhana, thanks your comment makes a lot of sense! so I should try to identify the parent and show it first? any tips on how I could do that would be awesome!

Comment: @Jai I fixed errors in markup.

Comment: @Juhana solved the problem see below, but your comment about parents was instrumental. I can't yet vote on comments but really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that jumps out at me is that you are using $('.active').Show() which is not a jQuery Method.  You want $('.active').show().  Notice the lower case "S".

In addition, you didn't close the H3 tag, and you are hiding the parent element.

Simple example with same logic:

```
<div class="a">
      <div class="b">Apple</div>
      <div class="c">Pear</div>
</div>

$(function(){
  $('.a').slideUp();
  $('.b').show();

  // No matter what you will never see .b or .c.  They will always be hidden
     when .a slides up

})
```

Comment: You are correct, but just fixing the method name does not solve the problem.

Comment: @user1167442 yeah that </h3> does exist in my code but must have been erased in copy. Adding different classes to the divs would be the best solution but unfortunately I can't change this aspect, which is why I'm posting this.

Comment: The way to do what you want to do could be something like:
$('li').not('.active').hide();
Or some version of that.  If you need the content to hide by sliding up, then you will need to move '.active') outside of the "<UL>" or "DIV" you need to slide up.

Comment: @user1167442, thanks for your explanation, closest to a solution to my vague question. I'm very new to jQuery and looks like my code isn't going to allow what I want to do, so I'm going to rework my code with your comments in mind.

Comment: @user1167442 this is what worked finally:
   $('.div_toggle').slideUp(); 
   $('.topnav a.active').parents().slideDown(); 
thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score -1):

it should be `.show()` not `.Show()`

working jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/MMdqp/

Comment: What does your comment mean?

Comment: It means that your example "works" only because you haven't included jQuery so nothing on the page gets hidden. Open the example and look in the error console.

Comment: Ah yes, small oversight on my part. Well here's a working example that's as close as I can get it to what the OP wants:

http://jsfiddle.net/MMdqp/1/